# codemirror - get the current word under the cursor

Tags: codemirror, text-cursor

Is there a way to get the current text under the cursor?
I don't mean the text of the entire line, but just the single word..
For example, if the cursor is actually in the middle of the word "orange" **-->** `ora|nge`,
I need to get the word "orange".

Any way to solve this is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Marijn for help, [`findWordAt`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#findWordAt) is what I was looking for:

```
editor.on('cursorActivity', function() {
    var A1 = editor.getCursor().line;
    var A2 = editor.getCursor().ch;

    var B1 = editor.findWordAt({line: A1, ch: A2}).anchor.ch;
    var B2 = editor.findWordAt({line: A1, ch: A2}).head.ch;

    console.log(editor.getRange({line: A1,ch: B1}, {line: A1,ch: B2}));
});
```

Comment: That's an oddly verbose way to say `var word = editor.findWordAt(editor.getCursor()); editor.getRange(word.anchor, word.head);`

Comment: `cm.getRange(...Object.values(cm.findWordAt(cm.getCursor())))`